# Drupal/Wordpress Fatal error: Cannot redeclare functions - Errors keep showing

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, fatal-error

I have a drupal site and inside i have a wordpress blog like that drupal_site/wordpress_blog.
When i did the implantation all seemed to work fine but now i am getting the following error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare timer_start() (previously declared in (path_of_mysite)/includes/bootstrap.inc:456) in (path_of_mysite)/blog/wp-includes/load.php on line 197

I have renamed the timer_start() but then i got another same error for another function.

So the problem is that drupal's functions "overrides" wp functions and renaming every wp core function not working.

Also i have tried at least the errors to not shown at my page, i have disable them from my drupal dashboard, i have tried via .htaccess,via index.php,also via phpmyadmin but this error keeps showing.

Update:I found the solution for the errors to not be shown,i just have added

```
error_reporting(0);
```

to wp-config.php.So at least there is something.

Any clue for the solution?

Comment: You might want to migrate your Wordpress site inside your Drupal site. There is a module to ease the migration: https://drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate

Answer (score 1):

Drupal and Wordpress are trying to declare the same function names. To solve this type of problems PHP had introduced namespaces in PHP 5.3, more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php, but saddly Drupal and Wordpress did not use namespaces.

My recomendation to avoid this problem is to install Drupal and Wordpress in different subdomains, so if your domain is `drupal_site.com`, use `blog.drupal_site.com` for Wordpress installation.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I will search for the namespaces because i don't know much about them.
I have install Drupal and Wordpress in different subdomains exactly as you said.But i want to use the drupal_site.com/blog instead of blog.drupal_site.com so that's why i have put my blog inside my site. But the blog.drupal_site.com steels be alive. And  drupal_site.com/blog is at the blog.drupal_site.com subdomain, i just use different path now.